# Eigenvalue of a Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A: \mathbb C^4 \to \mathbb C^4$ be a linear operator and let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with complex coefficents. If $c$ is an eigenvalue for $f(A)$, does there exists a eigenvalue $a$ of $A$ such that $f(a) = c$?

Please, explain why this is true or false.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What have you done so far? What is the condition for $c$ to be an eigenvalue of $f(A)$?

Comment: Hint: Express $A$ in Jordan normal form and then compute the diagonal elements of $f(A)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is true.  One proof is as follows: let $f(z) - c = (z-z_1)\cdots(z-z_d)$ be a factorization into linear factors.  Each $z_i$ satisfies $f(z_i) = c$. If $f(A)$ has $c$ as an eigenvector, then $f(A) - cI$ is not invertible.  Applying our above factorization, this means that the matrix product
$$
(A - z_1 I) \cdots (A - z_d I)
$$
fails to be invertible.  Thus, $(A - z_i I)$ is non-invertible for some $i$.  That is, $z_i$ must be an eigenvector of $A$.